# Problems using awk to select group of sequences from fasta file

Tags: unix, awk, bioinformatics, fasta

I would like to subset my fasta file to retrieve sequences that belong to a given population. The following is a sample of my file.

```
>CLocus_12706_Sample_44_Locus_36326_Allele_0 [JoJo_s113.fq; groupI, 125578, +]
TGCAGCATGCTGGTGAACGCGTCATCATAAGCCTGTTGGCGAGCCAGCAGAAGGCGGCATGGGCAGCACTTAATAGGACGCACGTCCTCTGTGTCA
>CLocus_12706_Sample_46_Locus_34641_Allele_0 [JoJo_s115.fq; groupI, 125578, +]
>CLocus_12706_Sample_69_Locus_37751_Allele_0 [LakeCamp_s033.fq; groupI, 125578, +]
TGCAGCATGCTGGTGAACGCGTCATCATAAGCCTGTTGGCGAGCCAGCAGAAGGCGGCATGGGCAGCACTTAATAGGACGCACGTCCTCTGTGTCA
>CLocus_12706_Sample_70_Locus_33595_Allele_0 [LakeCamp_s034.fq; groupI, 125578, +]
TGCAGCATGCTGGTGAACGCGTCATCATAAGCCTGTTGGCGAGCCAGCAGAAGGCGGCATGGGCAGCACTTAATAGGACGCACGTCCTCTGTGTCA
>CLocus_72879_Sample_136_Locus_80036_Allele_0 [NaknekRiver_s148.fq; groupV, 11333693, -]
TGCAGAACGAGATGAGGACAAACACACTCACCACTCTGTGGACATGTAGACGGCTGGCCTGTCCTACCAAGGACAAATACTCCCACAACAGTCCAA
```

Populations are the part of the id that includes, for example "LakeCamp" or "JoJo" or "NaknekRiver".

I tried to follow this post to figure out how to extract the sequences. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253499/extracting-subset-from-fasta-file

To do so, I executed the following, with "JoJo" being the population of choice here, and my input file being "fasta8c18subset.fa".

```
awk -vrs=">" 'BEGIN{t["JoJo"]=1}{if($1 in t){printf ">%s",$0}}' fasta8c18subset.fa
```

I didn't get an error when I ran this, but I also got no output.

As output, I would like to get the entire header and sequence associated with that population. So, if I am trying to extract "LakeCamp" samples for example, I would like the output file to contain the following

```
>CLocus_12706_Sample_69_Locus_37751_Allele_0 [LakeCamp_s033.fq; groupI, 125578, +]
TGCAGCATGCTGGTGAACGCGTCATCATAAGCCTGTTGGCGAGCCAGCAGAAGGCGGCATGGGCAGCACTTAATAGGACGCACGTCCTCTGTGTCA
>CLocus_12706_Sample_70_Locus_33595_Allele_0 [LakeCamp_s034.fq; groupI, 125578, +]
TGCAGCATGCTGGTGAACGCGTCATCATAAGCCTGTTGGCGAGCCAGCAGAAGGCGGCATGGGCAGCACTTAATAGGACGCACGTCCTCTGTGTCA
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Could you please post what is your desired output here? For above there are many problems in it, like -vrs should be -vRS and you are creating an array in BEGIN which will be executed before Input_file is getting read, and then you are trying to traverse through that array t which has no values in it so it is not printing anything, please show us desired output so that we could help you here.

Comment: Thank you so much! I edited my initial question to include what I need in my output file.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise you to use an available fasta format parser.

For instance, in python3, you can use the pretty efficient parser from [pyGATB](https://github.com/GATB/pyGATB/wiki/Use-pyGATB-Python3-package).

You could use it as follows:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from gatb import Bank

fasta_file = sys.argv[1]
pop_name = sys.argv[2]

def get_pop(header):
    """Extracts the population name from the fasta header."""
    return header.decode("utf-8").split(" ")[1].split("_")[0][1:]

for seq in Bank(fasta_file):
    if get_pop(seq.comment) == pop_name:
        print(">%s\n%s" % (
            seq.comment.decode("utf-8"),
            seq.sequence.decode("utf-8")))

sys.exit(0)
```

Running this with your example file (which strangely has an empty sequence for `CLocus_12706_Sample_46_Locus_34641_Allele_0 [JoJo_s115.fq; groupI, 125578, +]`):

```
./extract_pop.py test.fa "JoJo"
>CLocus_12706_Sample_44_Locus_36326_Allele_0 [JoJo_s113.fq; groupI, 125578, +]
TGCAGCATGCTGGTGAACGCGTCATCATAAGCCTGTTGGCGAGCCAGCAGAAGGCGGCATGGGCAGCACTTAATAGGACGCACGTCCTCTGTGTCA
>CLocus_12706_Sample_46_Locus_34641_Allele_0 [JoJo_s115.fq; groupI, 125578, +]
```

If you don't have python3, you can use Biopython's `SeqIO` module:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from Bio import SeqIO

fasta_file = sys.argv[1]
pop_name = sys.argv[2]

def get_pop(header):
    """Extracts the population name from the fasta header."""
    return header.split(" ")[1].split("_")[0][1:]

for seq in SeqIO.parse(fasta_file, format="fasta"):
    if get_pop(seq.description) == pop_name:
        print(">%s\n%s" % (seq.description, seq.seq))

sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems quite simple. I have tried to execute it on a mac and am encountering many issues -- old version of python, dos2unix not installed, possibly needing xcode upgrade, etc..., so need to sort these out to use this, but I think it should work well.

Comment: You may try other libraries, such as biopython, which is available for python2.

Comment: That would be very good, since I've been pulling my hair out all day trying to get this to work. Would I simply change the python 3 part of the code to biopython?

Comment: Alternatively, I have also been trying to make this work using mobaxterm (unix environment) on my PC. I've downloaded the python3 plugin, and have tried a zillion things to make it work, but am coming across error after error. Is there any particular reason that the program shouldn't work using mobaxterm (local terminal)? My current issue is "Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
LookupError: unknown encoding: UTF-8" But, if I can run it with biopython, maybe this wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I fiddled with a couple other things on the mac as well, and got to the point where at least I am no longer getting python warnings. Now, at line 4, I get "...from gatb import Bank ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gatb'". I tried to download git, and didn't get any compalints, but when i try to get the version, using "git --version" to check the installation, i get illegal instruction. When I look at where it is installed, and ask "which git", I get "usr/local/bin/git" though, so it should be there.....?

Comment: I added a version using biopython and python2. It works the same as the pyGATB one.

Comment: Regarding mobaxterm, I never used this, but I guess you would better do bioinformatics under mac OSX than under windows, since mac OSX is made natively with a unix environment. Things will likely be even simpler if you use a standard Linux distribution. There is even one made with bioinformatics in mind, but it doesn't seem up-to-date. You might try it in virtualbox on windows: http://environmentalomics.org/bio-linux-installation/

Comment: It worked!! Took me a while to get python2.7 on the mac, etc..., but hooray! Thank you. One last question, where/what is the code for specifying an output file? I'm guessing that this would be in place of the print command.

Comment: The code I gave prints the results to its "standard output", that you can redirect to a file using ">" on the command line: `./extract_pop.py test.fa "JoJo" > JoJo.fa`. It is of course also possible to write to a file from within the python code, but these comments are not a good place to discuss this.